How do you adjust SharePoint Online Microsoft PowerApps web part height
How do you set the size of a SharePoint Online Microsoft PowerApps web part to max width (~1440px) by 100px high? The PowerApps size is set to 1440px by 100px. The PowerApps web part appears to be set to approximately 1440px by 800px and the only adjusts diagonally, which changes the height & width proportionally. Currently the wed part has empty space above and below the PowerApps App.

The web part resizes only in the bounds of the SharePoint page container. You can't extend beyond that. If you know your Power App will run in a web part, size it in Power Apps accordingly.
The resizing in the SharePoint web part will always keep the aspect ratio of the Power App, so once you've hit the max size in the web part, that's the limit.
Planning for this will pay off. On the other hand, you might as well run the Power App in its own browser tab instead of confining it to a web part. Close the tab to return to the previous page.
